# VB.net XML Serialization/Deserialization, How to Put Attributes for Lists

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

If I wanted to serizlize and deserialize an XML like this in VB:

```
  <SeveralListsOfPeople>
      <ListOfPeople groupname="Friends">
          <Person name="John">
          </Person>
          <Person name="Mary">
          </Person>
      </ListOfPeople>
      <ListOfPeople groupname="Family">
          <Person name="Karen">
          </Person>
          <Person name="Kyle">
          </Person>
          </ListOfPeople>
      <ListOfPeople groupname="Enemies">
          <Person name="Ben">
          </Person>
          <Person name="Chris">
          </Person>
      </ListOfPeople>
    </SeveralListsOfPeople>
```

How would I add the attribute "groupname" to "ListsOfPeople"?  I can't figure out how to add attributes to lists or arrays.  I only know how to add attributes to objects and the root.

This is how I thought it should work:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<Serializable>
<XmlRoot("SeveralListsOfPeople")>
Public Class SeveralListsOfPeople
    Public Property ListOfPeople As List(Of Person)
    <XmlAttribute("groupname")> Public Property name() As String
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class

<Serializable>
Public Class Person
    Public Property title As String
    Public Property age As String
    <XmlAttribute("name")> Public Property name() As String
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It would help if you could show us the code you're using for what you know.

Comment: Your class `SeveralListOfPeople` doesn't look like it has a collection of lists. How are you representing more than one `ListOfPeople` nodes in each `SeveralListOfPeople`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3417462/69527) to a similar question, you'd need to create your own `PeopleCollection` class and implement `IXmlSerializable` to get this to work with `System.Xml.Serialization`.

However, since this is `vb.net` and we have XML Literals, I prefer using that and defining `ToXml` and `FromXml` methods for my classes.

This will give you what you're looking for without fighting with implementing `IXmlSerializable`.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim xml = <SeveralListsOfPeople>
                  <ListOfPeople groupname="Friends">
                      <Person name="John">
                      </Person>
                      <Person name="Mary">
                      </Person>
                  </ListOfPeople>
                  <ListOfPeople groupname="Family">
                      <Person name="Karen">
                      </Person>
                      <Person name="Kyle">
                      </Person>
                  </ListOfPeople>
                  <ListOfPeople groupname="Enemies">
                      <Person name="Ben">
                      </Person>
                      <Person name="Chris">
                      </Person>
                  </ListOfPeople>
              </SeveralListsOfPeople>

    Dim test = SeveralListsOfPeople.FromXml(xml)

    Console.WriteLine(test.ToXml)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Public Class SeveralListsOfPeople
    Public Property Lists As List(Of ListOfPeople)
    Public Function ToXml() As XElement
        Return <SeveralListsOfPeople>
                   <%= From l In Lists
                       Select x = l.ToXml %>
               </SeveralListsOfPeople>
    End Function
    Public Shared Function FromXml(ByVal xml As XElement) As SeveralListsOfPeople
        Return New SeveralListsOfPeople With
               {
                   .Lists = (From l In xml...<ListOfPeople>
                            Select ListOfPeople.FromXml(l)).ToList
               }
    End Function
End Class

Public Class ListOfPeople
    Public Property ListOfPeople As List(Of Person)
    Public Property name() As String
    Public Function ToXml() As XElement
        Return <ListOfPeople groupname=<%= name %>>
                   <%= From p In ListOfPeople
                       Select x = p.ToXml %>
               </ListOfPeople>
    End Function
    Public Shared Function FromXml(ByVal xml As XElement) As ListOfPeople
        Return New ListOfPeople With
               {
                   .name = xml.@groupname,
                   .ListOfPeople = (From p In xml...<Person>
                                    Select Person.FromXml(p)).ToList
               }
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Person
    Public Property title As String
    Public Property age As String
    Public Property name() As String
    Public Function ToXml() As XElement
        Return <Person name=<%= name %>>
                   <title><%= title %></title>
                   <age><%= age %></age>
               </Person>
    End Function
    Public Shared Function FromXml(ByVal xml As XElement) As Person
        Return New Person With
               {
                   .name = xml.@name,
                   .title = xml.<title>.Value,
                   .age = xml.<age>.Value
               }
    End Function

End Class

End Module
```

Comment: Looks like the class itself is a collection?